# how to make rviz subscribe laser scan topic

Tags: lidar, rviz, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

How could we make rviz subscribe to a topic of /tilt_scan[sensor_scan/laserScan ?
I use laser bag provided with laser_pipeline tutorial to access laser scan data

I am using fuerte.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43873/how-to-make-rviz-subscribe-laser-scan-topic/) by [Radhika](https://answers.ros.org/users/3209/radhika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Open a [LaserScan display](http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3